# Multiple independent component injection

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

My dagger configuration for an android project that i'm working on: 
Note: I've provided all the needed @Component, @Module, @Provides annotations wherever needed.

```
MainActivity {

@Inject A a;
@Inject B b;

 onCreate(){
    ComponentX.inject(this);
    ComponentY.inject(this);
 } 
}

ComponentX-> ModuleA ->providerA
ComponentY -> ModuleB -> providerB
```

As you can see, these are two completely independent components not related to each other in anyway except for at the point of injection.

During compilation I get the following error:

```
In file A.java
error: B cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
MainActivity.b
[injected field of type: B b]
```

Am I mistaken in thinking that multiple components can be used while using dagger 2 or is the application supposed to use one big component which takes care of all the injections?

Can anyone help me understand where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to have a single component, there are various ways to modularize them, but each object that you create, or inject values into, must have all its values provided by a single component.

One way you could restructure your code is to have ComponentY depend on ComponentX, or vice versa, e.g.

```
@Component(dependencies = ComponentX.class)
interface ComponentY {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

Or you could create a third Component, say ComponentZ, if ComponentX and ComponentY are completely orthogonal to one another.

```
@Component(dependencies = {ComponentX.class, ComponentY.class})
interface ComponentZ {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

Or you could just reuse the modules, e.g.

```
@Component(modules = {ModuleA.class, ModuleB.class})
interface ComponentZ {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

How exactly you decide to split it largely depends on the structure of your code. If the components X and Y are visible but the modules are not then use component dependencies, as they (and module depedencies) are really implementation details of the component. Otherwise, if the modules are visible then simple reuse them.

I wouldn't use scopes for this as they are really for managing objects with different lifespans, e.g. objects associated with a specific user whose lifespan is the time from when a user logs in to when they log out, or the lifespan of a specific request. If they do have different lifespan then you are looking at using scopes and subcomponents.

Comment: The composition method is what I have done currently as a intermediate solution. On the other hand, from my understanding, scopes were a different usage just like you mentioned. What I wanted to identify was whether this was the right approach, single target injection component which is a composition of multiple components( which are provided in library projects )

Comment: It's definitely a good approach, whether it's the right approach is up to you. Again it depends on what your 'api' is and how you want to modularize it.

Comment: It's definitely a good approach, whether it's the right approach is up to you. Again it depends on what your 'api' is and how you want to modularize it.

Comment: The only thing worth taking into considering is that if your module provider methods and the components are unscoped, then you'll get a new instance on each inject call. However, you can work around that if you store a reference for what you created in the module, and return that once it's created. It's kinda lengthy though.

Answer (score 2):

> is the application supposed to use one big component

Kind of, you should think of it in scopes. For a given scope, there is one component. Scopes are for example `ApplicationScope`, `FragmentScope` (retained), `ActivityScope`, `ViewScope`. For each scope, there is a given component; scopes are not shared between components.

(This essentially means that if you want to have global singletons in the `@ApplicationScope`, there is one application scoped component for it. If you want activity-specific classes, then you create a component for it for that specific activity, which will depend on the application scoped component).

Refer to @MyDogTom for the `@Subcomponent` annotation, but you can also use component dependencies for the creation of subscoped components as well.

```
@YScope
@Component(dependencies = ComponentX.class, modules=ModuleB.class)
public interface ComponentY extends ComponentX {
    B b();

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}

@XScope
@Component(modules=ModuleA.class)
public interface ComponentX{
    A a();
}

ComponentY componentY = DaggerComponentY.builder().componentX(componentX).build();
```

Comment: 1) Does this compile for you? Because these are two different scopes.

2) You are ultimately talking about about one component here by extending component Y from componentX. You've taken the inheritance route and I was thinking about the composition route (by choosing inter-component dependency).

Comment: Of course it compiles if you add the two custom scope annotations, YScope is a subscope of XScope. Think ActivityScope is a subscope of ApplicationScope.

Answer (score 0):

> is the application supposed to use one big component which takes care
>   of all the injections?

You can use `Subcomponent`. In your case components declaration will look like this:

```
@Subcomponent(modules=ModuleB.class)
public interface ComponentY{
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}

@Component(modules=ModuleA.class)
public interface ComponentX{
    ComponentY plus(ModuleB module);
}
```

`ComponentY` creation: `creationCompunentY = ComponentX.plus(new ModuleB());`

Now in `MainActivity` you call only `ComponentY.inject(this);`

```
MainActivity {

@Inject A a;
@Inject B b;

 onCreate(){
    ComponentY.inject(this);
 } 
}
```

More information about sub components can be found in [migration from Dagger1 guide](http://google.github.io/dagger/dagger-1-migration.html) (look at Subgraphs part), [Subcomponent JavaDoc](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Subcomponent.html) and [Component JavaDoc](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Component.html) (look at Subcomponents part).

Comment: In this case too, you are talking about composing it all into one big component which takes care of the injections. You are not exactly dealing with the scenario of having two separate components. Having two separate injects

Comment: I think, that composing final component before using it is much better that doing multiple injection like you suggest. Your `MainActivity` shouldn't know about how your dependencies  are distributed between `Components`. Are there two or three components etc. And you are free to change that distribution in order to provide easier testing or easier reuse without changing `MainActivity`.

Comment: @MyDogTom I kinda disagree that composing one "fat" component is better. I would like freedom to inject things directly in the class. In both ways, MainActivity has no clue about component creation, and only care about what is injected in it. I am not telling you are wrong, just this is different perspective of view, but I see this as limitation.